What is the expected number of trials until first success where trial probabilities for success improve in subsequent trials?
Trying to reach out to statistically minded people to help me understand how to calculate the probability of "success" and the Expected number of trials when the probabilities aren't uniform for each trial.
In my scenario, the rate of success at each trial number is as follows:

Trial 1: $31.92\%$
Trial 2: $48.62\%$
Trial 3+: $45.16\%$


What is the expected number of trials until the first success?

Looking through statistical resources, if the probability of success was always $31.92\%$, the Expected number of trials would be $\frac{1}{.3192}$ which is approximately $3.13$ trials.
When the success rate increases, intuitively, the trials would decrease since there should be better odds later, right?  I'm trying to google and search for rules/formulas to help me build something.  I thought about writing a simple program that would just simulate a large number to try to come at an answer, but I was hoping there was a closed form equation for this type of thought experiment.
This came about an an online card game I play as a hobby and it has my curiosity intrigued.  Those numbers are the success rates published by the game developer, and I'm curious if my actual rates matches up favorably or unfavorably to theirs.

Hint. Figure out by hand the probability that you succeed on the first or second trial. Then use what you know about constant success rate to figure out the expected number of trials from the third on.

You get $0.3192\times 1 + (1-0.3192)\times 0.4862\times 2 + (1-0.3192)\times (1-0.4862)\times \left(2+\frac1{0.4516}\right)$ or equivalently $1 +  (1-0.3192) +  (1-0.3192)\times (1-0.4862)\times \frac1{0.4516}$.

This response merely converts the ideas already expressed in the comments into a full answer.
This response will use the following identity:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nX^n = \frac{X}{(1 - X)^2} ~: ~|X| < 1. \tag1 $$
Let $~f(n)~$ denote the probability that the first success occurred on trial $~n.~$ Then, the expected number of trials equals
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ ~n \times f(n) ~\right]. \tag2 $$

Let $~p_1 = 0.3192, ~p_2 = 0.4862, ~p_3 = 0.4516.$
For $~i \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~3 ~\},~$ let $~q_i~$ denote $~(1 - p_i).$
In order for the first success to have been on trial $~n,~$ two things must have happened:

Every trial prior to trial $~n~$ must have failed.

Trial $~n~$ must have succeeded.


So:

$f(1) = p_1.$

$f(2) = q_1 \times p_2.$

$f(3) = q_1 \times q_2 \times p_3.$

$f(4) = q_1 \times q_2 \times q_3 \times p_3.$

$f(5) = q_1 \times q_2 \times (q_3)^2 \times p_3.$

$f(6) = q_1 \times q_2 \times (q_3)^3 \times p_3.$

$f(7) = q_1 \times q_2 \times (q_3)^4 \times p_3.$

$\cdots$


Therefore, the computation in (2) above may be expressed as
$$(1 \times p_1) + (2 \times q_1 \times p_2) + \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left[ n \times q_1 \times q_2 \times (q_3)^{n-3} \times p_3 ~\right]. \tag3 $$
So, the problem has been reduced to using the identity in (1) above to convert the expression in (3) above into a specific number.

Let $~A~$ denote $~(1 \times p_1) + (2 \times q_1 \times p_2).$ 
Let $~B~$ denote $~q_1 \times q_2 \times p_3.~$
Then, the expression in (3) above may be re-expressed as
$$A + \left\{ ~B \times \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left[ ~n \times (q_3)^{n-3} ~\right] ~\right\}$$
$$=A + \left\{ ~\frac{B}{(q_3)^3} \times \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left[ ~n \times (q_3)^n ~\right] ~\right\}. \tag4 $$
Further, using (1) above, you have that
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \left[ ~n \times (q_3)^n ~\right] $$
$$= \frac{q_3}{(p_3)^2} - \left\{ ~[ ~1 \times q_3 ~] 
+ [ ~2 \times (q_3)^2 ~] ~\right\}.$$
So, let $~\displaystyle C = \frac{q_3}{(p_3)^2} - \left\{ ~[ ~1 \times q_3 ~] 
+ [ ~2 \times (q_3)^2 ~] ~\right\}.$
Then, the expression in (4) above equals
$$A + \left\{ ~\frac{B}{(q_3)^3} \times C ~\right\}. \tag5 $$
Note that you have exact numerical values for $~p_1, ~p_2, ~p_3.~$
From these, you can determine the exact numerical values for $~q_1, ~q_2, ~q_3.$
Then, you can determine the exact numerical values for $~A, ~B, ~C.$
Then, you can convert the expression in (5) above into an exact number.

Not only does this analysis agree with my own, it is very clearly written and doesn't give away the prize at the end. Bravo!
